# How to avoid wireless headphones picking up white noise after x minutes of silence?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, headphones

I own a set of Sennheiser wireless headphones (hdr120) and after a period of silence the transmitter seems to shut off and the headphones pick up white noise.

Is there a way to disable that?

Alternatively, perhaps there is a program that can send a "ping" with a given interval if the computer audio device is not outputting any sound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These headphones listen for analog sound, and if they don't get it, the transmitter turns off after a bit.  Playing a silent audio file wouldn't register on them any more then...  nothing.  The only way to prevent the transmitter from turning off and the headphones from picking up static would be for a sound to be sent through at intervals shorter then the timeout period.  It MAY be possible to use a sound signal lower then human hearing (20 hz) or higher, (18-20 Khz) to satisfy it, which would not be audible to the listener.  In fact, now I am curious, and I have a pair.  I'm going to test this.

Comment: I tested this with a sound generated with a sound editor.  The sound was 15 hz, lower then human hearing. It was 5 seconds long, but I bet one second would be enough. It faded in, and out, to prevent a noticable pop.  It DOES WORK.  I could E-Mail the sound to you if you are still looking for help.

Comment: I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMaHF4h1jag but the white noise didn't solved.

Answer (score 1):

The least sophisticated solution to this, would be to create a shell script to play a silent audio file every now and then. If that frightens you, install a media player that can be used from the command line (winamp has plugins for that, for example) and set up a scheduled task in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PowerShell script like so, let's call it `TR120.ps1`:

```
while(1)
{
    (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\path\to\inaudible.wav").PlaySync();
    Start-sleep -seconds 100
}
```

(Possible improvement: keep `SoundPlayer` object and play it again? shouldn't really matter though)

Create a shortcut in the Startup folder with Target:
`powershell.exe -noLogo -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file "C:\path\to\TR120.ps1"`.

(Putting the `ps1` file in Startup doesn't work because because the default Execution Policy is `restricted`, and it's probably associated with a text editor anyways)

And of course you'll need an audio file, preferably inaudible. I've only managed to get it inaudible or mostly inaudible under some conditions, but after a long period of silence I can hear when it plays, possibly due to some auto-leveling built into the headphones. [Here's a file you can try.](https://instaud.io/zeg)